# Using MVVM on a View that has a long running process

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I have an example here that replicates what I am trying to accomplish. 
As the following code will show - I have ViewModel that updates a ObservableCollection Property bound to a View. Normally I would update the collection from a result retrieved from a Model, but hopefully this example will suffice.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MVVMWpf.ViewModel
{
    public class ListViewModel
    {

        public ObservableCollection<int> SomeObjectCollection { get; set; }

        public ListViewModel()
        {

            SomeObjectCollection = new ObservableCollection<int>();

        }

        public void Do()
        {
             for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++)
             {
                 int i1 = i;
                 SomeObjectCollection.Add(i1);
             }
        }

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this blocks this UI. It will only update the View when loop runs to completion. The way I solved it breaks MVVM concepts. That's why I need your help. I did it this way.

```
public class ListViewModel
{
    private delegate void LongRunningProcess();
    public ObservableCollection<int> SomeObjectCollection { get; set; }
    private ListBox listBox;
    public ListViewModel(ListBox listBox)
    {
        this.listBox = listBox;
        SomeObjectCollection = new ObservableCollection<int>();

    }

    public void Do()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
           for (int i = 1; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
           {
               int i1 = i;
               listBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                   new LongRunningProcess(() =>
                   SomeObjectCollection.Add(i1);
                 }});

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    }

}
```

As you can see the ViewModel now knows about the listBox element from the UI. And looking at the MVVM diagram only the View should have a reference to the ViewModel through binding. How does one overcome this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: How does one overcome what issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to let your loop unleash updates to the screen - some kind of DoEvents() will do:

```
public static void DoEvents() 
{ 
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Background,new Action(delegate { })); 
}
```

Add it and call that from within your loop.

---

Using timer as another option, your code should look somthing like that:

```
private System.Timers.Timer operationsTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
private int x;
```

in your ctor:

```
operationsTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler 
(operationsTimer_Elapsed);
operationsTimer.Enabled = true;
```

in your timer elpased:

```
operationsTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{ 
    operationsTimer.Enabled = false;
    //add item to collection code
    x++;
    if(x<100)
        operationsTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Lol funny, I actually found this right after posting the question. But that it throws an exception when I shut the program down...

Comment: Another option would be to use a timer instead of in-thread loop.

Comment: If I can handle that exception I it sounds like the solution I want. Is there a way to exit all threads on application close. Maybe I should listen to window.close events

Comment: How would I use a timer in this case. I would like to try that as another option. Thanks

Comment: I'll add the timer option to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), an easy way of performing async tasks with functionality for reporting progress as well as a completed event. Best of all, you don't have to invoke anything on the dispatcher, as the BackgroundWorker's functions are synchronized to the UI thread.